# How to gracefully shut down nuxt.js + serverMiddleware + express after an unhandled rejection

Tags: node.js, express, nuxt.js

TLDR: Is there a way to programmatically and properly shut down the Nuxt server while in the serverMiddleware?

---

I recently learned how create my own API inside Nuxt 2 through serverMiddleware. Before knowing serverMiddleware, I had to run my API in a separate backend. So I think I'm familiar with handling unhandled rejections.

Here's an example of my express backend code:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

const port = process.env.PORT

const server = app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`App is running on port ${port}`)
}) 

process.on("unhandledRejection", (err) => {
    console.log(err.name, err.message);
    console.log("Unhandled Rejection. Shutting Down.");
    server.close(() => {
      process.exit(1);  
    });
});
```

Now when using Nuxt, `app.listen()` and `server.close()` doesn't work because Nuxt is running its own server. While `process.exit(1)` does the job, from what I understand, that by itself isn't ideal.

Is there a way to programmatically and properly shut down the Nuxt server while in the serverMiddleware?

Comment: I don't think that you can shutdown something from the internal code. Meanwhile, depending on where your code is hosted, you could have a daemon who will be looking for the Nuxt app and restart it when needed.

Comment: I see. I'm planning to use heroku or netlify. I would probably check their docs and see if they help me with this problem. Thanks!

Comment: Netlify does not have node.js running servers. Heroku may have something but I'm not sure. I'm sure that PM2 can do that tho.